# Proof of the special case of Moore-Penrose Inverse $A^+=A^*(AA^*)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

What's the simplest proof to the equations $A^+=A^*(AA^*)^{-1}$ and $A^+=(A^*A)^{-1}A^*$ for the Moore-Penrose inverse? I am not taking any course about generalized inverses and I can not seem to find any reference which explains the proof clearly, or maybe it's just because I lack the searching capability as English is not my main language. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse of $A$ is defined by the following four equations:

1. $ABA = A$
2. $BAB = B$
3. $(AB)^* = AB$
4. $(BA)^* = BA$

There is one and only one $B$ that satisfies all of these properties, and that matrix we denote by $A^+$.

Now, let us suppose $AA^*$ is invertible. Note that $(AA^*)^* = AA^*$, and consequently, $$((AA^*)^{-1})^* = ((AA^*)^*)^{-1} = (AA^*)^{-1}.$$
Let $B = A^*(AA^*)^{-1}$. Note that,
$$AB = AA^*(AA^*)^{-1} = I,$$
hence $ABA = IA = A$ and $BAB = BI = B$, meaning both 1 and 2 are satisfied. Also $AB = I$ implies $(AB)^* = I^* = I = AB$, hence 3 is also satisfied.

The only condition left is 4. We have
$$(BA)^* = (A^*(AA^*)^{-1}A)^* = A^*((AA^{-1})^{-1})^*(A^*)^* = A^*(AA^*)^{-1}A = BA.$$

Thus, $B = A^*(AA^*)^{-1}$ is the one and only matrix satisfying the conditions 1-4, making $B = A^+$.

If $A^*A$ is invertible, then the other formula can be proven similarly.